# Programming User Interface(UI), best solutions in c#?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, user-interface

I was wondering if there are best well-known methods, architectures, 3rd party libraries, etc to help developers program UI?

I am thinking about something which would help in the following areas:

- When looking into the code written by someone else, 
  I would like to know instantly, what UI serves, what are the states of the UI,
  From which does the state depend on?
- Something which could clearly separate logic for each state

State for me would be the state of all components when:

- user run winform
- user makes a decision and executes some action, The result of his action
  is another state of UI Form
- user leaves the form
- etc.

For me as a developer, programming in mvc, which is a good, because allow to seperate logic(view, manipulating and data access) it is still confusing when I see events doing something, which to be honest I have to re-think in which situation that may occur, what and when it is doing...

Do you know what I mean?

Any suggestions greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WinForms this is hard, since the GUI and code behind is very tightly coupled.

I would recommend using WPF instead, and a MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) framework as  [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) to better separate the GUI from the logic. It's a much better model for development than WinForms ever was.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if there are best well-known methods, architectures, 3rd party libraries, etc to 
>   help developers program UI?

Why do you wonder? You have a 100% chance that, because there are more than one of them, the answer will never be no.

> When looking into the code written by someone else, I would like to know instantly, what UI 
>   serves, what are the states of the UI, From which does the state depend on?

Delusional. This will never happen even when standardizing the code base unless the cases are trivial.

At the end, regardless of how many patterns you follow, a complex UI is a complex UI and you won't get this down to the level of "how many types of burgers are at McDonald's". If you don't want to think, then work at McDonald's.

Patterns may help, but forms vary widely and, outside of simple showcase patterns, etc., they won't get you "instant, don't think" access to other people's code.

Comment: Of course you may always stick to your approach and develop how you want but .. it is the matter of invention. When certain things can be improved the people do it and as a result, we have lots of solutions, libraries, different approaches. Complex things are complex, but if we can do more to alleviate the complexity of the problem so that it is more ease to maintain the code and have an overall clear knowledge how this works, then the code is becoming less prone to errors and more understandable for other developers.

Comment: If there's an important message in this answer, it's that obsessive focus on design patterns has never made anyone's code better. That's not to say that such patterns aren't useful. But it's more important to design a functional app than it is to worry excessively about the patterns you follow to do so. There's a lot of truth in the assertion that complex code bases are, well, complex. No matter what design patterns you apply, there's going to be some ugliness as long as you're not dealing with superficial models. That's perfectly okay, as long as the code is written so that it makes sense.

Comment: Well said - that basically is it. Regardless how many patterns you follow, a complex UI is complex by definition and you never will get into it without spending some effort.